# How to output elements from Javascript array in two different tables?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array with 44 elements. I want to output these elements in two different columns. First 32 elements should be in Table 1 and other 12 should be in Table 2. I would like to use one for loop for this if possible. So far I only found solution that required two for loops. Basically I would use .slice(). First loop will loop through myArray.slice(1,32) and second myArrat.slice(32,44). Here is my code:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,....44];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.slice(1,32); i++) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);
} 

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.slice(32,44); i++) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```

Is there a way to do this in one loop? I would like to put them in two different dynamic created tables. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `i < myArray.slice(1,32)` will likely always be false.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single for loop for this, though I don't see why you wouldn't just use the two `.slice()` calls.

You could do this:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,....44];    

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (i < 32) {
        /* do something here */
    } else {
        /* do something else here */
    }
}
```